# How to make div grows following size of div on the right?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a page with a left menu (red), a content div (blue) and footer (green). So, the structure of my page is the following:

div main

.... div left_menu with float left

.... div content with float right

div footer (outside the div main).

The code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html{
height:100%;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


#main {
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  height:80%;
}

#left_menu{
  background-color:red;
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}

#content {
  background-color:gray;
  width:75%;
  float:right;
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
}

#footer {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">

<div id="left_menu">
<h1> My left menu</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">
 <p> Some content </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<p> My footer</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I put more content inside div content, this div increases it height, which is what I want. However, the left_menu keeps his same size and the footer does not go down (that is, the content is shown over the footer).

I thought that the div main would increase its height when content increases, so, it would push the footer down in the page. Moreover, since left_menu has height:100% (which, I think , means 100% of the height of div main), I thought that it would follow the height of the div on the right. But none of this is happening.

Thus, my question is: how can I make the left_menu div have the same size as the div on the right and the footer to appear below the main div, not under the div content?

This is the same code, but with more things written in the div content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html{
height:100%;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


#main {
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  height:80%;
}

#left_menu{
  background-color:red;
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}

#content {
  background-color:gray;
  width:75%;
  float:right;
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
}

#footer {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">

<div id="left_menu">
<h1> My left menu</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">
 <p> Some content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
 <br />
 <p> More content </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<p> My footer</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand what would you like to achieve from the description. Can you put some sketch or visualisation?

Comment: Instead of float, use flex and your problem is solved https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Or consider **clearing the float**...that will solve part of the problem...pushing the footer down.

Comment: @Nubzor I will edit the question to make it more clear. Give me some minutes. Thank you for the comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your HTML structure would allow you to use Flexbox as a solution. With flex you can tell the two menu and content items grow, align in a number of different ways.

I always find this article quite helpful as a resource: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
html{
height:100%;
}

body{
  width:80%;
  margin:0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content{ display:flex; 
align-items: stretch;
}
#main {
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  height:80%;
}

#left_menu{
  background-color:red;
  width:25%;
}

#right_content {
  background-color:gray;
  width:75%; 
  height:auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:blue;
}

#footer {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="left_menu">
      <h1> My left menu</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="right_content">
      <p> Some content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
      <br />
      <p> More content </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p> My footer</p>
</div>
```